# KnockoutJS code not outputting anything, but no error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api2

I have this Knockout JavaScript code...

```
var bikesUri = '/api/bikes/';

function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
    self.error(''); // Clear error message
    return $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: uri,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        self.error(errorThrown);
    });
}
self.getBikeDetails = function (item) {
    ajaxHelper(bikesUri + item.Index, 'GET').done(function (data) {
        self.detail(data);
    });
}
```

and this HTML..

```
<!-- ko if:detail() -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h2 class="panel-title">Bike Specifics</h2>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr><td>Bike Name</td><td data-bind="text: detail().CycleName"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Manufacturer</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Manufacturer"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Shop Category</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Category"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Retail Price</td><td data-bind="text: detail().RRP"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Our Price</td><td data-bind="text: detail().OurPrice"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Stock Level</td><td data-bind="text: detail().Stock"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
```

and this Data Transfer object.

```
public class BikeDetailsDTO
{
    public int Index { get; set; } // ID
    public string CycleName { get; set; } 
    public string Category { get; set; } // Pulled from Category Maps
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public double OurPrice { get; set; } // pulled from suppliers
    public double RRP { get; set; } //pulled from suppliers
    public int Stock { get; set; } // pulled from suppliers

}
```

The API works perfectly.  when you access the API through the browser it returns exactly what I want it to do..  Return the relevant bike by its ID..  Wonderful.

When I go to access the view that the Interface is on, I get nothing.  No error, when I click on the Show details button to execute the "getBikeDetails" it shows the table, but no data.. nothing.  All other parts of the API are perfectly fine apart from this code and its driving me nuts!!!!!

Can anyone shed any light on this please as I really cant see it..

Comment: is `self.detail` observable or array ? form your view i believe its observable  use `with` on div(`<div data-bind="with:detail">`) and later use `data-bind="text:CycleName"` on td . remove containerless that should work like gold

Comment: apologies for not putting that code snippet in.  Its an Observable Array  self.bikes = ko.observableArray();

Comment: then you are not using any `foreach` to bind if you dont want to use foreach simple try `data-bind="text: detail()[0].CycleName` use index

Comment: @supercool nothing seems to be working on it at all and I don't understand why.  The code is adapted from the asp.net EF6 BookService tutorial and works like gold there.  I'm missing something but I don't know what..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple modify your view like this to make it work use `with` and remove containerless

```
<div class="panel panel-default" data-bind="with:detail">
    <div class="panel-heading">
         <h2 class="panel-title">Bike Specifics</h2>

    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped" data-bind="foreach:$data">
        <tr>
            <td>Bike Name</td>
            <td data-bind="text:CycleName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manufacturer</td>
            <td data-bind="text:Manufacturer"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26449/)** you can use nested div(if it's ok)

Containerless helps as you have class applied on div check fiddle using containerless **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26451/)**

Comment: OH MATE!!!!!!!!  I could seriously give you a big hug and a kiss right now!!!!!  Ive been racking my head on this since about 7 am this morning before asking anyone and till about 11pm last night..  Thank you soooo muchly!!